# How to speed up performance of Django Rest Framework serializer with source from Model's method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have API endpoint based on DRF 3.6.3 which already responsive (<1s response time). But after I add new serializer field with source from model's method, it perform very slow (more than 30s response time).

**edit:** so the performance problem because the field that I process on the method is Foreign Key.

this is my snippet code:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    a_name = models.CharField()
    b_name = models.ForeignKey(to=OutletProduct)

    def all_name(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.a_name, self.b_name)
```

Serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productid = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id')
    productallname = serializers.CharField(source='all_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('productid', 'productallname')
        read_only_fields = ('productallname', )
```

I only need to do small customization of my API output, and I don't think override `to_representation()` is right approach for this.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Just make sure the fields you are calling are not FK. I haven't faced performance issue by adding a field pointing on a callable so far.

Comment: yes, you are right. the performance issue because one of its field that I process on the method is a FK. I will update my question.
and now after I put the field on `setup_eager_loading(queryset)`, I have no performance issue anymore. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

based on comment about FK, I override `setup_eager_loading(queryset)` on my serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productid = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id')
    productallname = serializers.CharField(source='all_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('productid', 'productallname')
        read_only_fields = ('productallname', )

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        # select_related for 'to-one' relationships
        queryset = queryset.select_related('b_name')
        return queryset
```

snippet on my view:

```
prepared_serializer = ProductSerializer.setup_eager_loading(product_list)
products = ProductSerializer(prepared_serializer, many=True)
```

let my know if there's a better (faster performance) answer.
thank you!